# Converting GPT to MBR while Windows 10 is Installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, mbr, gpt

I'm very curious about this one. I have a UEFI Laptop, Lenovo Ideapad 320 to be exact, and the hard drive partition is on GPT format. If I use a third party to change the partition format without losing data, GPT to MBR, what will happen to my OS? Will it stop booting? Or will it keep booting? Or will I encounter a bootloop?

PS: I only have 1 hdd inside
Thank you!

Comment: GPT is better than MBR. Why do you want MBR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting GPT to MBR is an unsupported transition. Most people are trying to move MBR to GPT, so I would strongly consider why you want to do this.

If you can successfully convert your GPT drive to MBR, then you have to change your BIOS settings to legacy mode and disable UEFI booting. Technically, the OS should work ok after this.

It should go without saying, but you must, must, must **backup all your data** before you attempt to do this.